# Ruby on Rails: simple share button and pop-up window

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook

I want to simple share button on my page, which after clicked open pop-up window to share the current url.

I try to do it using facebook developers code (from official site)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button

but when I add ruby variable request.url (but with data-href="http://myweb.com" it works)

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="#{request.url}"></div>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

it doesn't work - I have the window below

[image]

How can I do it correctly ?

Comment: Can you post the rest of the code you're using for this ?

Comment: No problem, the request has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to open up the share button in a new window? Are you also using the correct variable for that model you have it in?

Comment: <%= link_to @review.gitrepo, "#{@review.gitrepo}", :target => 'new' %> I have this listed in one of my files and the target => 'new' will open up the link in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching it to this since I'm assuming you're using erb

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<%= request.url %>"></div>
```